# How can I set different notifications sounds for different WhatsApp groups?

Tags: notifications, whatsapp-messenger

How can I set different notification sounds for different WhatsApp groups? I can set different notification sounds for different contacts individually, but I want to know whether I can set different notification sounds for different groups.

Comment: I don't think that can be done as WhatsApp doesn't allows doing that !

Answer (score 1):

WhatsApp doesn't support different group notificaion sounds for groups as of now. There's no way to do it.

Comment: There should be. i have a very noisy group so i need to silence that but now i get no alerts from other contacts. must use another app for those communications like text or email. Seems like a simple enhancement to make the app a lot better.